# Kivy - Change a video source using button

Tags: python, kivy

I have these in my .py file

```
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'NBA Highlights'
        Window.maximize()
        return MainApp()

class MainApp(BoxLayout):
    vid = "Top 10 Plays of 2015"

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainApp,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_Vid(self, next_vid):
        self.vid = next_vid
        return self.vid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

and this in my .kv file

```
<MainApp>:
    Button:
        text: 'Click to change video'
        on_press: root.change_Vid('Top 10 Assists of 2015')
    Video:
        source: 'Videos/' + root.vid + '.mp4'
        state: 'play'
```

When I run the codes, it plays the video 'Top 10 Plays of 2015', but when I press the button it doesn't change to 'Top 10 Assists of 2015'.

I can see the root.vid changing but it does not update the source of the video widget. How can I change the video when I clicked the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `Video` object never learns that the `vid` property of its root has changed. Instead, make `vid` a property of `Video`:

```
<MainApp>:
    Button:
        text: 'Click to change video'
        on_press: root.change_Vid('Top 10 Assists of 2015')
    Video:
        id: video
        vid: 'Top 10 Plays of 2015'
        source: 'Videos/' + self.vid + '.mp4'
        state: 'play'
        on_vid: self.source = 'Videos/' + self.vid + '.mp4'
```

And change the handler:

```
def change_Vid(self, next_vid):
        self.ids.video.vid = next_vid
        return self.ids.video.vid
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it work by editing your code into: self.ids.video.source = next_vid

Comment: @KPA actually I forgot the crucial line: an event handler for `on_vid`, see edited code